# Insert data through a package calling a procedure

Tags: plsql, insert, package, procedure

How can I insert data with the following procedure values calling a package:

```
PROCEDURE insert_analysis (
    p_profile   IN t_array_of_number,
    p_beam          IN t_array_of_number,
    p_ts                      IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_min       IN NUMBER,
    p_max        IN NUMBER,
    p_avg        IN NUMBER,
    p_sigma      IN NUMBER,
    p_roi      IN NUMBER,
    p_y_max                   IN NUMBER,
    p_y_min                   IN NUMBER,
    p_offset                  IN NUMBER,
    p_width                   IN NUMBER,
    p_iteration_id            IN NUMBER,
    p_parent_ts               IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_cup                   IN NUMBER,
    p_cupratio               IN NUMBER,
    p_beam_center_position    IN NUMBER,
    p_left                   IN NUMBER,
    p_right                IN NUMBER,
    p_profile             IN NUMBER,
    p_cup_gain         IN NUMBER,
    p_roi_beam         IN NUMBER,
    p_profiler           IN NUMBER)
```

When I try the below it doesn't insert:

```
exec_analysis.insert_analysis (TO_TIMESTAMP('10-SEP-0214:10:10.123000','DD-MON-RRHH24:MI:SS.FF'),
            100,
            100,
            100,
            100,
             100,
             100,
            100,
             100,
             100,
             100,
            TO_TIMESTAMP('10-SEP-0214:10:10.123000','DD-MON-RRHH24:MI:SS.FF'),
             100,
             100,
             100,
            100,
             100,
             100,
             100,
             100,
  100);
```

Comment: Halfer can you try to give that statement using trim.

Comment: You don't fill the first two parameters p_profile and  p_beam. It should actually give error.

Comment: I have tried filling those values Mottor. It doesnt work . Could you please provide me the sample one to add the values.

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Comment: What collection type is t_array_of_number?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will give you a idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddInTable(Id IN NUMBER, Name IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA(ColumnId, ColumnName)
    VALUES(Id, Name);
END;
/
```

To call the procedure:

```
AddInTable(Id => 3, Name => 'Sara');
```